# Pasting multiple data frames together while keeping data in specific row and columns

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

So right now I have an master data frame with 230 rows and 15132 column (all labeled with specific column and row names) with the value 0 stored in each observation. I have multiple data frames with differing columns and rows that I would like to paste into this master data frame while maintaining the correct placement. Each of these data frames consist of various combinations of the row/column names of the master data frame. How would I go about doing this?

```
dempty <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
rownames(dempty) <- c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
colnames(dempty) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")


d1 <- data.frame(matrix(1, nrow = 2, ncol = 3))
rownames(d1) <- c("x", "y")
colnames(d1) <- c("b", "c", "d")

d2 <- data.frame(matrix(2, nrow = 3, ncol = 4))
rownames(d2) <- c("v", "w", "x")
colnames(d2) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

d3 <- data.frame(matrix(3, nrow = 4, ncol = 2))
rownames(d3) <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
colnames(d3) <- c("d", "e")

dfinal <- data.frame(matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, "1;2", "1;2", 0, 2, 2, "1;2", "1;2", 0, 2, "2;3", "1;2;3", "1;3", 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3), nrow = 5, ncol= 5))
rownames(dfinal) <- c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
colnames(dfinal) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of what you want.  Two columns and a few rows in each data frme will be sufficient.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my code as such with dempty being the empty master data set, and d1/d2/d3 being the dataframes needed to be pasted in. As you can see from the desired final output, only specific instances have been overwritten (sometimes more than once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop should populate `dfinal` with values from `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`.  It can be easily edited for your actual problem.

```
## get row an col names of master data to be populated
cols<-names(dfinal)
rows<-row.names(dfinal)
## iterate through the master data frame
for(i in 1:length(cols)){
  for(j in 1:length(rows)){
    ## if df1 contains matching col/row names use ifelse to replace
    if(cols[i] %in% names(df1) & rows[j] %in% row.names(df1)){
      ## if current row/col in dfinal is still 0 replace with df1 value, else append df1 value
      dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] <- ifelse(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] == 0, df1[rows[j],cols[i]], paste0(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]],";",df1[rows[j],cols[i]]))
    }
    ## if current row/col in dfinal is still 0 replace with df2 value, else append df2 value
    if(cols[i] %in% names(df2) & rows[j] %in% row.names(df2)){
      ## if current row/col in dfinal is still 0 replace with df2 value, else append df2 value
      dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] <- ifelse(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] == 0, df2[rows[j],cols[i]], paste0(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]],";",df2[rows[j],cols[i]]))
    }
    ## if current row/col in dfinal is still 0 replace with df3 value, else append df3 value
    if(cols[i] %in% names(df3) & rows[j] %in% row.names(df3)){
      ## if current row/col in dfinal is still 0 replace with df3 value, else append df3 value
      dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] <- ifelse(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] == 0, df3[rows[j],cols[i]], paste0(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]],";",df3[rows[j],cols[i]]))
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is almost exactly what I need. Is there a way to perhaps append instead of replacing a value if matching rows/columns has multiple observations? For example in my sample matrices, row x column has a value of 1 in df1 and a value of 2 in df2. Is there a way to not just overwrite the 1 with 2 and instead have 1;2 be the final value?

Comment: To clarify, what is `dfinal` originally populated with? `0`s that need to be replaced? or `NA`s?

Comment: Yes, originally dfinal is populated with 0s that need to be replaced (dempty)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `ifelse()` function to check if `dfinal` value is still `0`.  If so, `df` value replaces `0`, otherwise value is appended to existing value with `;` in between values.  I hope this helps!

Comment: I was thinking of something along the lines of if((cols[i] %in% names(df1) & rows[j] %in% row.names(df1)) & df1[rows[j],cols[i]] %!in% dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]]){
      dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]] <- paste(dfinal[rows[j],cols[i]], df1[rows[j],cols[i]], sep = ";"), but I get the error argument is of length 0

Comment: No problem.  if this resolves your issues please accept the answer so others can clearly find the solution (it also helps me out).  Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Using this sample data:

```r
dat <- `dimnames<-`(data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=5)), list(letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:5]))
dat
#   A B C D E
# a 0 0 0 0 0
# b 0 0 0 0 0
# c 0 0 0 0 0

df1 <- `rownames<-`(data.frame(B=2:3, C=22:23), c("a", "c"))
df1
#   B  C
# a 2 22
# c 3 23
```

You can brute-force replacements with this:

```r
dat[,colnames(df1)] <- Map(function(x, y, rn) replace(x, rn, y),
                           dat[,colnames(df1)], df1,
                           list(match(rownames(df1), rownames(dat))))
dat
#   A B  C D E
# a 0 2 22 0 0
# b 0 0  0 0 0
# c 0 3 23 0 0
```

If your data has row indices (row names) as an actual column, though, it would likely be easier and more robust to `merge` or use one of the `dplyr::*_join` functions with some post-merge cleanup. Base R's `merge` does support merging by row name, though it feels less fluid:

```r
newdat <- merge(dat, df1, by=0, all=TRUE)
newdat
#   Row.names A B.x C.x D E B.y C.y
# 1         a 0   2  22 0 0   2  22
# 2         b 0   0   0 0 0  NA  NA
# 3         c 0   3  23 0 0   3  23

(cleanupvars <- gsub("\\.x$", "", grep("\\.x$", colnames(newdat), value = TRUE)))
# [1] "B" "C"
for (nm in cleanupvars) {
  newdat[[nm]] <- ifelse(is.na(newdat[[paste0(nm, ".y")]]), newdat[[paste0(nm, ".x")]], newdat[[paste0(nm, ".y")]])
  newdat[,paste0(nm, c(".x", ".y"))] <- NULL
}
newdat
#   Row.names A D E B  C
# 1         a 0 0 0 2 22
# 2         b 0 0 0 0  0
# 3         c 0 0 0 3 23
newdat$Row.names <- NULL
```

(Column order is not maintained.)

This last method is clunky, no doubt.